# Better way to hold a shower niche than silicone

Tags: shower, waterproofing

My contractor installed a shower niche (commercial one, aluminum or stainless) but tells me that having it holding just by the silicone caulking is enough.

I'm concern that over time, since it doesn't fit so snuggly, it will move and water will seep in. Especially from the top.

It fits nicely against the side of the enclosure, but there is some space allowing it to jiggle around a bit. What would be the correct way to secure it in place and be sure that water doesn't get in the wall?

Is there some stronger adhesive than silicone I could use which would keep water out? The border is about a quater inch thick. The niche sits *on* the shower pane and sticks out by about a quarter inch too.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: (also: I did not mean to create a new [niche] tag. If anyone knows the proper steps to remove it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's **properly** siliconed, it will be very secure and very dry.

When you (or a major manufacturer) build a fish tank in the past many decades, there is no frame (sometimes a completely cosmetic, non structural plastic thing that looks like a frame is used to trim up the top and bottom. It does not hold the tank together or the water in.)

The only thing holding a modern (glass) fishtank together, and keeping the water in it, is silicone caulking (for fishtanks, *not* the mold-and-mildew resistant type, as it kills fish) properly applied to properly cleaned glass and properly cured.

The bottom joint on a fishtank is subject to considerably more water pressure than a niche in your shower is.

Now, if it's not properly applied, sure, it could leak or fall out. But that's not the fault of the material, that's the skill and care of the worker installing it.

Comment: That's super helpful. Is there any hard rules for *properly siliconed* ? What I guess was missing, in this case, was pressure, as the niche slid forward curing cure. I'll try again with pressure to hold it tight. I'm wondering if there's any extra care I should take

Comment: Clean, clean some more and then clean. Also, leave it to cure for a good long while without being disturbed, once it's set properly in place. If, as your pictures imply but your question does not state, it fell out, call the people who installed it and make them put it back right, since presumably you already paid for it to be installed right, and they installed it wrong, instead...